# Can a C program be executed, in the same makefile as it is being built?

Tags: c, makefile

I have a makefile which builds my .C project, and produces an executable file. I know this can then be run from using the command ./(NAME) from the terminal.

My question is this - is it possible to actually build AND run within the makefile, so that i would just be able to type 'make' in the terminal, and the program would be built and run, all from this one file & command? (without the need of manually running the executable file).

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes; it is possible.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I don't really know makefiles very well, but if your main executable is called `test`, you can do: `test: $(CC) test.cpp -o test && ./test`

Answer (score 3):

No idea what is you makefile, but you could do something like that:

```
PROGARGS=

.PHONY:all run

all:prog

#...

run:all
    ./prog $(PROGARGS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can.

For example:

```
TARGET=hoge
CC=gcc

.PHONY: compileandrun
compileandrun: $(TARGET)
    ./$(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).c
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c
```

If you have this `Makefile` and the source code `hoge.c` in your writable current directory, the program will be compiled and run with `make` command.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are good; however, you can use this other variant (a quick-and-dirty solution).

Suppose your `makefile` has this line to build your program:

```
NAME:
    gcc source.c -o NAME
```

You can add your running command directly below:

```
NAME:
    gcc source.c -o NAME
    ./NAME
```

This does the same as `&&` concatenation: it runs the first command, and if successful, the second command too.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you sequence your makefile dependencies correctly, there is nothing stopping you from running you C program from the makefile. That said, most people would expect a makefile to just build the file and not also run it at the same time.

I would recommend just writing the make command and the run command in a single line in the command line. This way you only need to press enter once but don't need to do anything fancy in the makefile itself. If your shell supports history completion, the next time you want to build and run again you only need to press "UP" and "ENTER"...

```
make && ./NAME
```

If you really want to put everything inside the makefile, I would recommend creating a separate "run" target in your makefile to reduce the chance of confusion, like in jdarthenay's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36824652/90511).